# The smart pointer from cracking the code interview

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, smart-pointers

```
struct Data
{
    ~Data()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> class SmartPointer
{

public:
    SmartPointer(T* ptr)
    {
        ref = ptr;
        ref_count = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
        *ref_count = 1;
    }

    SmartPointer(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        ref = sptr.ref;
        ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
        ++(*ref_count);
    }

    SmartPointer<T>& operator=(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        if (this == &sptr)
            return *this;

        if (*ref_count > 0)
            remove();

        ref = sptr.ref;
        ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
        ++(*ref_count);
        return *this;
    }

    ~SmartPointer()
    {
        remove();
    }

    T getValue()
    {
        return *ref;
    }

private: // protected:
    T* ref = nullptr;
    unsigned* ref_count = nullptr;

    void remove()
    {
        --(*ref_count);
        if (!*ref_count)
        {
            delete ref;
            free (ref_count);
            ref = nullptr;
            ref_count = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
//    Data data;

//    auto data = new Data;
//    delete data;

    auto data = SmartPointer<Data>(new Data);
}
```

Saw the above implementation of a smart pointer on cracking the code interview 6th ed.

I changed protected members to be private and it still seem to work. Do we really need them do be protected?

If I understand it correctly, we can relate the above to a shared pointer. And we get close to unique pointer by doing

```
SmartPointer(SmartPointer<T>& sptr) = delete;
```

What are some of the features `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` have but are missing on `SmartPointer`? I guess this is something an interviewer might ask.

Comment: The `malloc` alone makes this solution suspicious. I'd say whomever wrote this isn't using C++ in their day to day.

Comment: if this is supposed to be a shared pointer, the reference count and data cannot be in the pointer class

Comment: For the purpose of demonstrating a smart pointer behavior can't I just get rid of that `malloc` and use member `unsigned ref` directly? Should the interviewer complain if I do that?

Comment: Compare with specifications? It clearly has nothing to do with unique_ptr but with shared_ptr the differences are massive.

Comment: An interviewer is just as likely to ask you how you would go about fixing a broken car. All of the code sample stuff should be out of the way before you get interviewed, and after that the interviewer is more interested in your problem-solving techniques than code-slinging abilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private and protected are only different if the class is inherited from.  Since your `SmartPointer` has no classes inheriting from it, there is no difference.